# Why is ON DELETE SET NULL still not implemented in the Entity Framework 6? Is there a snag?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

It still is not possible to configure a relation with the ON DELETE SET NULL rule using Entity Framework code first. As a workaround you have to load all the related entities in memory and *then* on deletion of the parent entity EF will issue SQL commands to set their foreign keys to Null.

This, while it is trivial to implement this yourself using something like:

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE dbo.Guests DROP CONSTRAINT Guest_PreferredLanguage");
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE dbo.Guests ADD CONSTRAINT Guest_PreferredLanguage FOREIGN KEY (LanguageID) REFERENCES dbo.Languages(LanguageID) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL");
}
```

(Example take from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048561/entity-framework-set-delete-rule-with-codefirst).)

I can see no problems with this approach: Loaded child entities will remain in sync with the database because EF will update (set to null) their foreign keys and Reference properties, and that other records in the database are affected does no harm as they have not been loaded anyway.

So, why is this feature still missing then? Is there some hidden snag?

Comment: id like to see that feature too, but its more a question for http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: @philsoady I cannot find the topic there. It just seems to easy to add it: it is not very different from the cascading delete is it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the product's feature request site (https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/)

Comment: @GertArnold The question will indeed be off-topic if there is no valid reason for this feature to be missing other than that the Entity Framework team just has not prioritized it.

Comment: There's a work item to implement it in EF7. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/333

Comment: A hidden snag at least for SQL server: the SQL server at least cannot resolve dual/circular relations. Lets say you have a person and an address table. A person can have a home address and a working address. You design that in a way that the person has two keys that point to the same address table. SQL server is not able to resolve that. Entity Framework is able to resolve that as long as you load the person and only then delete the address (which sets the home-address-fk-id to null). But for single relations the above helps.

Comment: Downvoted because it's not a programming question is it?  Doesn't mean it's not a valid question... it just doesn't belong on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is probably not implemented because normally changes only affect the objects which are actually in the unit of work. Cascades are not scalable.

And I also think soft deletes are better in most cases. Maybe thats something for you?

You might also want to look into Domain Driven design. That also covers the correct use of units of work (with aggregates).

Btw your solution edits the database in the seed method. It might be better to do that a Up() method of a migration.

Comment: *The feature is probably not implemented because normally changes only affect the objects which are actually in the unit of work. * The same holds true for cascading deletes, which are configured by default by EF. Soft deletes are a different topic of debate ;-)

Comment: Then they should remove cascading deletes also. At least then they are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version=3.1.10.0 onwards.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Guests>()
            .HasOne<Languages>(g => g.Language)
            .WithMany(l => l.Guests)
            .HasForeignKey(g => g.LanguageID)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

Note, ***DeleteBehavior.SetNull***