# EF : why child records are not deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, code-first

I have the following structure:

```
public partial class Driver 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //....

    #region Vistracks Required Fields

    public virtual ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver { get; set; }

    #endregion
}


public partial class ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Driver")]
    public int DriverId { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }

    public int? ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsServerError { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Driver)
    .WithOptional(ad => ad.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

then I try to remove a record from ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver for concrete driver:

```
        var driver = await (from i in _db.Drivers where i.AspNetUser.UserName.Equals(model.Email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) select i).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (driver == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();

        driver = mapper.Map<VistrackDriverInfoDomain, Infrastructure.Asset.Driver>(model, driver);
        driver.IsVistracksAdded = true;
        driver.VistracksDateSync = DateTime.Now;
        driver.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver = null;

        _db.Entry(driver).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

no errors, all other changes are saved. But record in ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver is not deleted. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Set WillCascadeOnDelete to true

Comment: @LucianBumb, can't set WillCascadeOnDelete to true (requirements from customer).

Comment: That settings is responsible to delete child’s, if you cannot use it that means you need to do it manually in your code

Comment: @LucianBumb but string driver.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver = null; does not mean delete manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove a child record you need first to get it from database and then you can set it to null:

```
var driver=_db.Drivers.Include(x=>x.ProblemSyncToVistracksDrivers)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.AspNetUser.UserName.Equals(model.Email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
driver.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver = null;
 await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

more explanations you can find here [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912625/how-to-update-fk-to-null-when-deleting-optional-related-entity)

Answer (score 1):

In your model, you specified:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Driver)
    .WithOptional(ad => ad.ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This specification indicates that every `ProblemSyncToVistrackDriver` object belongs to exactly one `Driver`, not zero, not two: exactly one. This Driver can be found in property `Driver`.

The Driver that you will find in property `Driver` has an optional property `ProblemSyncToVistracksDriver`. This means, that if that property is null, entity framework might assume that there is no `ProblemSyncToVistrackDriver` that belongs to this `Driver`.

What you did, is that you specified a proper one-to-zero-ore-one relation. Every `Driver` has zero or one `ProblemSyncToVistrackDriver`, every `ProblemSyncToVistrackDriver` belongs to exactly one `Driver`.

If you've got a `Driver`, and you'll set its `ProblemSyncToVistrackDriver` to zero, then what you are saying is that this `Driver` has no `ProblemSyncToVistrackDriver` anymore. Normally, CascadeOnDelete would have taken care that the former `ProblemSyncToVistrackDriver` of this `Driver` would be deleted. You specified that you don't want this automatic deletion, hence the `ProblemSyncToVistrackDriver` is not deleted. That's why it is not deleted.

If you specify that you want manual-deletion, you'll have to delete the item yourself.