# How do I delete a user in ASP.NET Identity which has an optional relationship to other entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm creating an MVC 5 app and using Identity Framework for authentication. An IdentityUser has a one-to-many optional relationship with a Content entity:

```
public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }    
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public AppUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

}

public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

when deleting a user I don't want the child Content items to be deleted, I want their CreatedByIds to be set to null. If I use the following code from my controller

`IdentityResult result = await UserManager.DeleteAsync(user);`

I get an error:

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Contents_dbo.AspNetUsers_CreatedById". The conflict occurred in database "ApplicationDbContext", table "dbo.Contents", column 'CreatedById'.
The statement has been terminated.

I have solved this by writing my own implementation of the DeleteUserAsync in the User Manager:

```
public async Task<int> MyDeleteUserAsync(AppUser user, IOwinContext context)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        db.Users.Remove(db.Users.Include(u => u.Contents).Single(u => u.Id == user.Id));
        return await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Which i then call from my controller like so:

```
await UserManager.MyDeleteUserAsync(user, HttpContext.GetOwinContext());
```

This works because it loads the Contents into memory so that Entity Framework can set the Foreign Keys to null before saving.

What is the correct way to achieve this using the built in functionality of Entity Framework's UserManager?

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048561/entity-framework-set-delete-rule-with-codefirst?

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at that.