# How to Set FK to null after parent record has been delete, MVC Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc application, in it there are two tables ApplicationUser and Employee, so basically when a new user is registered and employee is created.

```
 public class HR_Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int HR_EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

}

what i wish to achieve is that when Application User is deleted i would like the FK to be set to null, currently the code give error because Employee is dependent on User. i read that this is not supported in EF6, i also tried solution suggested in 
[Entity Framework: Set Delete Rule with CodeFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048561/entity-framework-set-delete-rule-with-codefirst)
was not successful.

any ideas on how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: you check out [ https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx] cascase delete

Comment: Arvind, i am familiar with cascade delete. this isn't the case here, in this example it is one to one relationship with foreign key constraint in one of the tables.